# How can I find if value in hashmap a does not exist in hashmap b

Tags: java, hashmap

I have two different hashmaps with query results, though the 2 hashmaps are different sizes hashmap, and I'm trying to find records that exist in hashmap A that don't exist in hashmap B.

I'll post my code so far; I did the comparison via sql and I get the result I want, but when I tried to put it in code I'm not successful.  I hope you can point me in the right direction. Thanks in advance

```
HashMap<Integer, HashMap<String, Object>> mapA = new HashMap<>();
HashMap<Integer, HashMap<String, Object>> mapB = new HashMap<>(); 

int m=0;

for (int j = 0; j < mapA.size(); j++) {
    for (int k = 0; k < mapB.size(); k++) {
        if (!mapA.get(j).get("folio").toString().equals(
             mapB.get(k).get("folio").toString())) {
            m++; // count many records not exist on mapB
        }
    }
}
System.out.println(m);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an error in the logic. You want to find not existing in A records, but incrementing counter everytime when values of both iterating HashMaps don't equal (you will get much greater m in this case). Your code should look like.

```
for (int j = 0; j < mapA.size(); j++) {
    boolean found=false;
    for (int k = 0; k < mapB.size(); k++) {
        if (mapA.get(j).get("folio").toString().equals(
            mapB.get(k).get("folio").toString())) {
            found=true;   
            break;
        }
    }

    if (!found){
       m++; // count many records not exist on mapB
    }
}
```

Also there is additional possible error. In general case you have to make comparision not after toString method but compare objects (I think you didn't ovverite toString method of your objects to return valid identifier to compare them. And in most cases it will return not what you need. Or in other words you should ovveride equals methods of all you possiblle objects in hashmaps and use next code for comparision:

```
mapA.get(j).get("folio").equals(mapB.get(k).get("folio"))
```

In your case (with toString) comparision can return always false, because typical toString return class and ID of the objects.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understood your approach. A more proper way to do that would be (in pseudo code):

```
For each element in Hashmap A:
  If !HashmapB.contains(element):
    ++Counter;
```

Comment: ill try that pseudocode, basically what i need is to get all elemments from hashmap a that doenst exist on hashmap b.  I let you know if that works

Comment: also i mention that the hashmaps are different size hashmap b has as index as string and also stores a objet

Comment: Different sizes of the hash maps don't matter for this one. As long as you do the correct comparison it should do the trick.

Comment: well still no luck, any other suggestions?

Comment: @Cobol Can you edit your question to show what you tried and what happened?

Comment: sure, I have 2 resultsets mapped on a hashmap, i was trying to find values that don't exist on the second resultset. I was trying to find those records with the code i posted. Puhan posted that solution and worked.